# How to create a horizontal transparent scroll bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, scrollbar

I am trying to create something like this (look at the time), you can basically slide it horizontally.

[image]

Can anyone give me any suggestions on how to do this in iOS?

Comment: you can use scrollView to achieve this but I thing you are better off with uidatepicker.

Comment: check this https://github.com/pppoe/LightMenuBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) which you can constrain to just horizontal movement.  The [Scrolling demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008023) may help to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy:

1. create a scrollview with frame of (xOrigin,yOrigin,SCREEN WIDTH,Height).
2. set the content size to (CONTENT WIDTH, Height).
3. setShowsHorizontolScrollIndicator to no to hide the scroll indicator.

Note: Width of the contentSize property should be greater than the frame width to make it horizontally scrollable.